# How to ensure data security in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Say I'm building a chat room app using Firebase. In my client code, I make direct writes to the production database (i.e, the chat content, etc.)

How can I ensure that clients do not have DIRECT access to my database? If someone decompiles my apk, and changes the table name where I make access, then they'll be able to write to any of my databases.

I need clarification on how Firebase is secure without providing a middle layer of security between the client and server (by not letting the client access the Database directly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set permissive rules for your paths in Firebase, i.e.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
       // users is readable by anyone
       ".read": true,

       // users is writable by anyone
       ".write": true
       }
    }
    "important_table": {
       // important_table is readable by anyone
       ".read": true,

       // important_table is NOT writable by anyone
       ".write": false
       }
    }
}
```

More: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/